# Flexbox - One Scrollable, One Fixed?

Tags: css, flexbox

I experience some issues working with flexbox. Here is where I want to get:

[image]

I want to have a flexbox styled window. On the left, taking 2/3 of the screen, I will ahve some longer content. On the right, taking 1/3 of the screen, I want to have a background image that always fills the viewport height, even if I scroll down on the left.

The current html structure roughly looks like:

```
    <div class="layout horizontal wrap">
        <div class="flex flex-2" id="main-content">
            {{ scrollable content }}
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-1" id="image">
            {{ fixed image }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for you input!

Answer (score 2):

Of course don't use flex on body.

```css
html , body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
   display: flex;
}

.big {
  width: 66.66%;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.small {
  width: 33.33%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">
<h1>Scroll</h1>
<p>
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</p>
<p>
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</p>
<p>
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</p>
<p>
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</p>
<p>
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</p>
</div>
<div class="small"> Fixed
</div
```

Answer (score 1):

set the height for the blue div to 100vh;
100vh is 100% of viewport

```
the-blue-div{
   height:100vh;
}
```