# Two column (one fixed, one scrolls) using React/React Flexbox Grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am after the following functionality:

- Navigation column (left) stays locked and occupies `100vh`, or 100% of the browser's current height,
- Content column (right) scrolls, showing content.

Right now, the following code works well, when the browser is sized-down the Navigation column stacks on top of the Content column.

However, I'd like to keep this functionality while forcing the Navigation column to be fixed.

So far I've tried using `position: fixed;` under `.nav-column` in `App.css`, this resulted in the Navigation overlapping the Content.

I'm using React 16.7.0 and 'react-flexbox-grid'. Checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406161/flexbox-one-scrollable-one-fixed) out as well, this solution just involved using basic HTML/CSS and has nothing to do with React nor React Flexbox Grid.

Any help? Here's the code:

(Sorry, I can't get the snippet to run. Guessing it's the `react-flexbox-grid` stuff.)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-flexbox-grid';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid fluid className='app-main'>

        <Row>
          <Col className='nav-column' xs={12} sm={3}>
            <h1>Nav</h1>
          </Col>

          <Col className='content-column' xs >
            <h1>Content</h1>
            <div>
            <p>
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
            </p>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>

      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```css
.app-main {
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.nav-column {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.content-column {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: darkkhaki;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I took some liberty with your design thinking this is what you are after from your description. The biggest changes are removing the `<Row>` since that complicates scrolling only one column and solved the rest with CSS.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Grid, Row, Col } from "react-flexbox-grid";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <Grid fluid className="app-main">
      <Col className="nav-column" xs={12} sm={3}>
        <h1>Nav</h1>
      </Col>

      <Col className="content-column" xs>
        <h1>Content</h1>
        <div>
          <p>
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
            aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
            reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
            pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
            culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
          </p>
        </div>
      </Col>
    </Grid>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

CSS

```
.app-main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav-column {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: aqua;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-column {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: darkkhaki;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

The app is written as a function to make using the live editor easier. So here it is in the live editor.

https://codesandbox.io/s/n4n779pj4m

Comment: I like this answer Randy, although it results in the Navigation dominating the whole page when you downsize the window. But the fixed column functionality is there.

Comment: The content column has fallen "under" the nav column. Your code does that because you have your grid set to fluid. If you remove the `fluid` attribute it shouldn't do that anymore.

Comment: yeah, it does though. looks like I'll have to use good ol' Flexbox to achieve what I need.

Comment: Seems like a choice between the React tax and simplicity to me. Flexbox being the simplicity part. :-)